# CONVERT statement in SAS Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I'm running the following code, which is supposed to compare two columns of a SAS dataset for me:

```
PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE loandata.tv_curve AS
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(INT, srp_contract_lifetime) as srp_contract_lifetime, rpa_tv
FROM loandata.sas_f_risk_parameter_cn
WHERE rpa_tv IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, srp_contract_lifetime);

QUIT;
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error messages:

```
ERROR: Function CONVERT could not be located.
ERROR: Function CONVERT could not be located.
ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: INT.
```

How can I convert my srp_contract_lifetime variable into an int correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONVERT` is a TSQL (Microsoft SQL Server) function, not a [sas](/questions/tagged/sas) function.  In SAS you do conversions using `input` and `put`.

```
PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE loandata.tv_curve AS
SELECT DISTINCT input(srp_contract_lifetime,12.) as srp_contract_lifetime, rpa_tv
FROM loandata.sas_f_risk_parameter_cn
WHERE rpa_tv IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY input(srp_contract_lifetime,12.);

QUIT;
```

As Gordon notes, this may not even be needed, as SAS only has numeric and character.  Only use the `input` if it's stored as character; otherwise remove it.

Answer (score 1):

SAS only has numbers (floating point) and fixed length character strings.

If your variable is a number and it only has integer values then there is nothing to convert. If you want to remove the fractional part you could use INT(), FLOOR(), CIEL() or ROUND() functions depending on how you want to do the conversion.

If your variable is a character string then you could use either the INPUT() or INPUTN() function.